# Homebrew: How to install an old version of a formula which uses a bottle?

Tags: macos, qt, terminal, homebrew

I'd like to use an older version of `poppler` which is needed in some program for inline PDF display. *I can't use the newest due to incompatibility with the program.*

I already managed to find out that to install `poppler` with the option `--with-qt` I need an older version of the `poppler.rb` formula. I got this version from github homebrew-core tap and I think it should be working. So far so good. Now in case I try to install this formula `--with-qt` I get the message that qt is outdated, which is due to the fact that the newest homebrew qt can't be installed on my OS anymore.

Therefore I'd need to install an old version of qt too. Hence I also got the older formula for `qt-5.11.2` from github, modified the formula to be `qt@5112` instead just `qt` and tried to install it, but I always get the message that this `@5112`formula is trying to download some bottle from

```
https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/qt@51122-5.11.2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
```

which doesn't exist because its called just `https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/qt-5.11.2......`. Does anyone know how to resolve this? I.e.: how to rename some bottle? Or the formula for `qt-5.11.2` from `qt` to `qt@5112`?

Or is there a better way to hack this brew formula?

I'd really apprechiate some useful inputs. Thanks!

---

`qt@5112.rb` formula I am trying to install (modified from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/360923286c0f1a6a1325ada578df030bf579009f/Formula/qt.rb) for `@5112`):

```
# Patches for Qt must be at the very least submitted to Qt's Gerrit codereview
# rather than their bug-report Jira. The latter is rarely reviewed by Qt.
class QtAT5112 < Formula
  desc "Cross-platform application and UI framework"
  homepage "https://www.qt.io/"
  url "https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.11/5.11.2/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.2.tar.xz"
  mirror "https://qt.mirror.constant.com/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.2/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.2.tar.xz"
  mirror "https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/blfs/conglomeration/qt5/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.2.tar.xz"
  sha256 "c6104b840b6caee596fa9a35bc5f57f67ed5a99d6a36497b6fe66f990a53ca81"
  head "https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git", :branch => "5.12", :shallow => false

  bottle do
    sha256 "8c77b5762267b127cc31346ac4da805bbfd59e0180d90e1e8b77fb463e929d60" => :mojave
    sha256 "096d8894b25b0fdec9b77150704491993872a7848397a04870627534fb95c9e3" => :high_sierra
    sha256 "0464be51d0eb0a45de4a1d1c6200e1d9768eec5e9737050755497a4f4de66a08" => :sierra
    sha256 "22e9abc0b47541bb03b2da7f6a19c5d7640ea2314322564551adc3d22305806e" => :el_capitan
  end

  keg_only "Qt 5 has CMake issues when linked"

  option "with-examples", "Build examples"
  option "without-proprietary-codecs", "Don't build with proprietary codecs (e.g. mp3)"

  deprecated_option "with-mysql" => "with-mysql-client"

  depends_on "pkg-config" => :build
  depends_on :xcode => :build
  depends_on "mysql-client" => :optional
  depends_on "postgresql" => :optional

  # Restore `.pc` files for framework-based build of Qt 5 on macOS, partially
  # reverting <https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/140954/>
  # Core formulae known to fail without this patch (as of 2016-10-15):
  #   * gnuplot (with `--with-qt` option)
  #   * mkvtoolnix (with `--with-qt` option, silent build failure)
  #   * poppler (with `--with-qt` option)
  patch do
    url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/e8fe6567/qt5/restore-pc-files.patch"
    sha256 "48ff18be2f4050de7288bddbae7f47e949512ac4bcd126c2f504be2ac701158b"
  end

  # Chromium build failures with Xcode 10, fixed upstream:
  # https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=840251
  # https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849689
  patch do
    url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/962f0f/qt/xcode10.diff"
    sha256 "c064398411c69f2e1c516c0cd49fcd0755bc29bb19e65c5694c6d726c43389a6"
  end

  def install
    args = %W[
      -verbose
      -prefix #{prefix}
      -release
      -opensource -confirm-license
      -system-zlib
      -qt-libpng
      -qt-libjpeg
      -qt-freetype
      -qt-pcre
      -nomake tests
      -no-rpath
      -pkg-config
      -dbus-runtime
    ]

    args << "-nomake" << "examples" if build.without? "examples"

    if build.with? "mysql-client"
      args << "-plugin-sql-mysql"
      (buildpath/"brew_shim/mysql_config").write <<~EOS
        #!/bin/sh
        if [ x"$1" = x"--libs" ]; then
          mysql_config --libs | sed "s/-lssl -lcrypto//"
        else
          exec mysql_config "$@"
        fi
      EOS
      chmod 0755, "brew_shim/mysql_config"
      args << "-mysql_config" << buildpath/"brew_shim/mysql_config"
    end

    args << "-plugin-sql-psql" if build.with? "postgresql"
    args << "-proprietary-codecs" if build.with? "proprietary-codecs"

    system "./configure", *args
    system "make"
    ENV.deparallelize
    system "make", "install"

    # Some config scripts will only find Qt in a "Frameworks" folder
    frameworks.install_symlink Dir["#{lib}/*.framework"]

    # The pkg-config files installed suggest that headers can be found in the
    # `include` directory. Make this so by creating symlinks from `include` to
    # the Frameworks' Headers folders.
    Pathname.glob("#{lib}/*.framework/Headers") do |path|
      include.install_symlink path => path.parent.basename(".framework")
    end

    # Move `*.app` bundles into `libexec` to expose them to `brew linkapps` and
    # because we don't like having them in `bin`.
    # (Note: This move breaks invocation of Assistant via the Help menu
    # of both Designer and Linguist as that relies on Assistant being in `bin`.)
    libexec.mkpath
    Pathname.glob("#{bin}/*.app") { |app| mv app, libexec }
  end

  def caveats; <<~EOS
    We agreed to the Qt open source license for you.
    If this is unacceptable you should uninstall.
  EOS
  end

  test do
    (testpath/"hello.pro").write <<~EOS
      QT       += core
      QT       -= gui
      TARGET = hello
      CONFIG   += console
      CONFIG   -= app_bundle
      TEMPLATE = app
      SOURCES += main.cpp
    EOS

    (testpath/"main.cpp").write <<~EOS
      #include <QCoreApplication>
      #include <QDebug>

      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        qDebug() << "Hello World!";
        return 0;
      }
    EOS

    system bin/"qmake", testpath/"hello.pro"
    system "make"
    assert_predicate testpath/"hello", :exist?
    assert_predicate testpath/"main.o", :exist?
    system "./hello"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood one things. `qt` and `qt@5112` are two different names. They are recognized as two different packages by Homebrew.

But the old `proppler` `depends_on "qt"`, not `qt@5112`. You have to rename the formula file `qt@5112` back to `qt`.

Comment: I know that the old `poppler`depends on `qt` by default but I'd change that to be depending on `qt@5112` so it should take the old qt as dependency. Changing back to use `qt` as dependency doesn't solve my issue at all. Thats kind of the original problem since I can't use the newest qt and therefore poppler doesn't install using the normal formula. Therefore I started the workaround as described: Do you know how to handle the bottle naming? So `brew install qt@5112.rb` installs the old one but using the name `qt@5112`.

Comment: @avermaet `poppler` depends on `qt`, but it doesn't specify a version. So you can install both the `poppler` and `qt` with old versions. Install `qt` 5.11.2 first, `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/360923286c0f1a6a1325ada578df030bf579009f/Formula/qt.rb`. Then the dependency is satisfied and you can install the old version `poppler`, `brew install url/to/old/poppler.rb`.

Comment: I understand your idea and tried to do it like this, but then I run into problems because qt requires full Xcode installed, not just command-line-tools. And also the necessary version of Xcode is not available on my OS anymore. If I remove the rquirement for Xcode in the poppler formula, I'll get the error Error: An exception occurred within a child process: ArgumentError: /usr/local/Cellar/poppler/0.81.0/lib/libpoppler-qt5.dylib: no such file even though I have valid but outdated qt-5.11.2 from bottle/brew.